# Multiple foreign keys in one table referring to different columns in other table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables.

Table 1: customers

```
| id | name | item_name                   | item_type                   |
| -- | ---- | --------------------------- | --------------------------- |
| 1  | john | fk->items.name or items.id? | fk->items.type or items.id? |
```

Table 2: items

```
| id | name | type      |
| -- | ---- | --------- |
| 1  | sink | utilities |
```

How do I fetch values in `customers.item_name` and `customers.item_type` from the `items` table? I know I can use foreign keys but I am confused which columns to refer to create foreign keys. How do I even call them using php statement?

Comment: The FK is normally the PK of the other table. So item_id. You wouldn't normally store item_type in customers unless type varied according to customer, in which case you wouldn't normally store item_type in items (unless you wanted a default item_type for instances where it wasn't specified in customer)

Comment: got it now! thanks so much. So how do I display the values of `items.name` and `items.type` if I store only `items.id` in the **customers** table?

Comment: At this point, 5 minutes in the company of any basic, introductory book or tutorial would be useful

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. I was not asking for any code, just asking for a quick suggestion. I had a doubt and you cleared it. Anyway, my original question is solved now. Wish I could mark your comment as answer. Thanks again!

Comment: Don't store item_name and item_type in customer - you could end up with a valid item_name which is not related to a valid item_type. Just store item_name you can enrich the type when querying. AND I would store item_id rather than item_name in a junction table rather than customers (ie a customer can have many items)

Comment: @P.Salmon Yeah, I've recreated the tables to have only the `items.id` in customers table. The item details, I figured out, can be called through appropriate SQL query. Thanks for the suggestion. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you're looking for something like this:

```
SELECT c.`id` as `customer_id`, c.`name` as `customer_name`,
       i.`name` as `item_name`, i.`type` as `item_type`
  FROM `customers` c INNER JOIN `items` i ON c.`item_name` = i.`name`
```

Comment: I think this adds to the OP's confusion